# Xamarin.iOS UICollectionView App crash when device is rotated for iOS 9.3

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, screen-rotation, ios9.3

In my app I am using UICollectionView to show grid view for custom cell containing Image and text. To support all screen sizes I have overridden 
IUICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegate's GetSizeForItem method. Every thing works great from iOS 8.1 to 9.2(Tested on simulator and device).
For iOS 9.3 simulator grid view renders correctly. But as soon as I rotate screen it crashes with following error:

> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException
>   Reason: -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x9065398 Native stack trace:     0   CoreFoundation
>   0x08e38494 **exceptionPreprocess + 180    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x091abe02 objc_exception_throw + 50  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x08e42253 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275  3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x08d7789d ___forwarding_** + 1037
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x08d7746e
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14    5   CoreFoundation                      0x08cf0cdb CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale + 203    6   Foundation
>   0x00da5770 -[NSString compare:options:range:locale:] + 175    7
>   Foundation                          0x00da56b9 -[NSString
>   compare:options:range:] + 72  8   Foundation
>   0x00dab7f2 -[NSString caseInsensitiveCompare:] + 81   9   UIKit
>   0x0156e021 -[UIPhysicalKeyboardEvent _matchesKeyCommand:] + 357   10 
>   UIKit                               0x0147035e -[UIResponder
>   _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 446    11  UIKit                               0x01470531 -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:target:] + 913     12  UIKit
>   0x0147019b -[UIResponder _keyCommandForEvent:] + 48   13  UIKit
>   0x0123e287 -[UIApplication handleKeyHIDEvent:] + 380  14  UIKit
>   0x0121234d _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6743  15  CoreFoundation
>   0x08d4ae5f **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 15  16  CoreFoundation                      0x08d40aeb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523  17  CoreFoundation                      0x08d3ff08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032    18  CoreFoundation
>   0x08d3f846 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     19  CoreFoundation
>   0x08d3f65b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   20  GraphicsServices
>   0x09b3f664 GSEventRunModal + 192  21  GraphicsServices
>   0x09b3f4a1 GSEventRun + 104   22  UIKit
>   0x01218eb9 UIApplicationMain + 160    23  ???
>   0x18c98020 0x0 + 415858720    24  ???
>   0x18c97e18 0x0 + 415858200    25  ???
>   0x18c95f98 0x0 + 415850392    26  ???
>   0x18c95cd4 0x0 + 415849684    27  ???
>   0x18c95e60 0x0 + 415850080    28  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
>   0x088cee81 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 705  29  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
>   0x08a7e0af mono_runtime_invoke + 127  30  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
>   0x08a82f71 mono_runtime_exec_main + 401   31  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
>   0x08a82d35 mono_runtime_run_main + 629    32  libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
>   0x0893ac8d mono_jit_exec + 93     33  TutorMeNot.iOS
>   0x001ff440 xamarin_main + 2384    34  TutorMeNot.iOS
>   0x001da5a1 main + 113     35  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0a62ca25 start + 1  36  ???
>   0x00000003 0x0 + 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not more related to the code. Here are my observations which resolved my issue.

I am using TabBarController. In one of the tab I am using UICollectionView with custom cell.
When I run App on iOS 9.3 simulator it displayed my collection view correctly.

To rotate simulator Keyboard shortcut "Command+arrow" is used.
As soon as I pressed command it's getting crashed.
But when I rotate simulator using Hardware -> Rotate options menu it worked fine.

Also I tested this on iPod device(iOS V9.3.2) and worked perfectly.
For test purpose I created sample UICollectionView App using Objective-C. When I build and run that sample on iOS 9.3 simulator it worked fine with no any crash on screen rotation.

Hope Xamarin team will look for this problem.